# Silence, Listening, Body Language, Miscommunication

Tags: pragmatics

Do linguists study silence, listening, and/or body language as types of communication? Also, do they study miscommunication in general? If so, what type of sub fields of linguistics would these topics be under?

Comment: I don't see how this is a question about the content of linguistics, it's a question about personal opinions of what the domain of linguistics is. It's an invitation to engage in "No true Scotsman" squabbles. Virtually anything in the domain of cognition and information is potentially of interest to *some* linguist somewhere. The tag "pragmatics" pretty much summarizes the linguistics of silence.

Comment: The answer to the first two questions are Yes and Yes. The third question is much too broad for an answer in this site's format.